# How to find data in mongodb by array from array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have collection in mongodb like below:

```
{   
  "_id": "xyz",
  "title" : "title+",
  "foodBeverage" : [
    "Expert 1"
],
"cuisine" : [
    "Afghan",
    "American",
    "Asian",
    "Bistro"
  ]
}
```

I want to with below array:

```
var arr1 = ["Asian"];
```

I want query to match using arr1. Like if value in arr1 exist in collection with cuisine, then return result.

Hope you get how I want filter.

Could any one assist.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.collection.find({ cuisine: { $in: [ "Asian" ] }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) in your query, like this :

```
db.test.find(
  {cuisine:
    {$in : ["Asian",...]   <= here your arr1
    }
  }
)
```

It will return your document if any of the 'cuisine' values matches with any of your arr1 values